# In Angular 2, How to create instance of class with generic type

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Angular 2 application and need to pass generic component of type so final out after processing data I want like following;

```
 this.myCollection = [
        { path: 'myPath', component: SurveyFormComponent },
        { path: 'yourPath', component: SurveyFormComponent },

    ]
```

I have define class of Generic DataType

```
export class DynamicRouteDataModel<T>{
path:string;
component: T;

constructor(path:string){
    this.path = path
 }
```

}

### in component

```
private routeObject: DynamicRouteDataModel<SurveyFormComponent>;

  private assembleDynamicRoutes(){
    this.dynamicRoutesData.forEach(routeItem => {       
         this.routeObject = new DynamicRouteDataModel<SurveyFormComponent>(routeItem.routeURL);
        //this.dynamicRoutes.push({"path":routeItem.Rout })
    });
}
```

My issue is when create instance of DynamicRouteDataModel, I get path not sure how to pass the typeof component

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your question. Are you asking how to create a `new T()`? Or are you trying to find out what `T` is, given a type of `DynamicRouteDataModel<T>`?

Comment: when I create instance of DynamicRouteDataModel<T> I only get path not component which i believe I already pass when I create instance by saying private routeObject: DynamicRouteDataModel<SurveyFormComponent>;